# I can't get records from .net core mvc web api database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I couldn't solve it in any way, can you please help?
I added web api to my .net core mvc project. I can return values as string or json, quite normally. But when it comes to the database, I have a problem. I am getting a null error. No matter how hard I searched, I couldn't figure it out. The smallest answer helps a lot.
[image]

[image]

[ApiController] When I add it, my app doesn't open at all. When I make a comment line, it opens. But I can't call database methods. The same operations can be called seamlessly in the webui layer.
**Startup.cs**

[image]
[image]

[image]

Appsettings
[image]

Can you please help?

Fail:

```
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at zfc.webapi.Controllers.zfc.GetReferrer() in C:\Users\mderv\Desktop\zfc\zfc.webapi\Controllers\zfc.cs:line 26
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Csproj
[image]

[image]

Repository

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please review [ask] and [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: can you please share the API action capture(the first one is not showing the full code)

Comment: I've added the error message, thanks for the warning.

Comment: and a capture for the signature of your ChatRepository and EfProfileRepository
it's probléme related to injection

Comment: I called it in Startup.cs by making the following definition. But I keep getting errors where exactly should I look?
 services.AddScoped<ChatRepository, EfChatRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ReferrerRepository, EfReferrerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ProfileRepository, EfProfileRepository>();

Comment: i added a comment with a full explication of the issue.

Comment: No problem could you please add your code so that we can fix it quickly for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshots and error so far I am assuming you haven't register the service in `startup.cs` file correctly.

Here I am adding a complete example for you how you can access data from database using your architecture.

Abstract:

```
public interface IChatRepository
{
    object GetDataFromDatabase();
}
```

Concrete:

```
public class ChatRepository : IChatRepository
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public ChatRepository(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public object GetDataFromDatabase()
    {
        var dataFromDatabase = _dbContext.PrinterJobs.ToList();
        return dataFromDatabase;
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have injected a `dbContext` class instance here to access database object. This `dbContext`, `IChatRepository` and  `ChatRepository` need to be registered in `startup.cs` file.

**Startup:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                    .AllowAnyHeader()));
         
    services.AddScoped<IChatRepository, ChatRepository>();
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
           
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
            });
}
```

**AppDbContext:**

```
public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
       
    public DbSet<PrinterJob> PrinterJobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PrinterJob>().ToTable("PrintJob");
    }

    internal object Query<T>(string v, string name, int employeeId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

`PrinterJob` sample model class:

```
public class PrinterJob
{
        [Key]
        public int PrinterId { get; set; }
        public string PrinterName { get; set; }
        public int PrintedBy { get; set; }
        public int TotalPrint { get; set; }
}
```

Database script:

```
CREATE TABLE PrintJob 
(
    [PrinterId] [int] PRIMARY KEY  IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [PrinterName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [PrintedBy] [int] NULL,
    [TotalPrint] [int] NULL,
 )
```

**Note:** add some sample data into the table once you create the table from about script.

`appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

**Note:** make sure you are referring a correct database to access your data accordingly.

Controller:

```
    [Route("api/ZfcData")]
    public class ZfcDataController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IChatRepository _chatRepository;

        public ZfcDataController(IChatRepository chatRepository)
        {
            this._chatRepository = chatRepository;
        }
      
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Route("GetDataFromDatabase")]
        [ActionName("GetDataFromDatabase")]
        public object GetDataFromDatabase()
        {
            var callRepository = _chatRepository.GetDataFromDatabase();
            return Ok(callRepository);
        }
        
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Hope it would guide you through, and help you to get resolve your problem and implementations.

Comment: Hello, I realized the mistake I made yesterday. I could not access the database methods because the name of the method I was injecting and the name of the controller did not match. Thank you very much for your explanation. An exact answer.

Comment: Its my pleasure to assist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dependecy injection to use your chatRepository and the injection it's not well configured ,

```
services.AddScoped<InterfaceOfMyReposiory,ImplementationOfMyRepository>();
```

So let's suppose that your ChatRepository is :

```
public class ChatRepository :IChatRepository {
 //some special impelementation
}
```

and you have an interface like this :

```
public interface IChatRepository {

// some great methods definitions
}
```

so in your startup.cs class you should configure it like this :

```
services.AddScoped<IChatRepository ,ChatRepository>();
```

you can check more in details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:%7E:text=ASP.NET%20Core%20supports%20the,controllers%20in%20ASP.NET%20Core.).

in your case this should solve the null exception :
`ChatRepository` : `interface`

`EfChatRepository` and `EfGenericRepository`  : implementation

```
services.AddScoped<ChatRepository ,EfChatRepository>();
```

`EfChatRepository` inherit the implemntation of `EfGenericRepository`

Comment: I looked it up but I named it chatrepository instead of Ichat repository. I've added layers to the question, can you help please? I really need help.

Comment: without sharing your chatrepository code i can't help with this.

Comment: @dervisaygan you can make a capture please ?

Comment: I shot all the episodes related to the chat repository. It works fine as a web project in the Webui layer. I can use database in webui layer but not in web api. I added the additional shots to the question. Thank you so much. @Houssem

Comment: you need to understand what i writed in my response and trying to apply it by yourself.
it's not matter the name of your file what's is matter is the goal and what she do.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my mistake was somewhere else entirely and it was very simple.
Class
public class zfc : ControllerBase
while doing the inject process
public HomeController
I did it in the form. It was a simple name mistake. Thank you.